# Remove even appearance of elements from list with Lisp or PROLOG

Tags: lisp, prolog

I have to delete even appearance of element from list using LISP or PROLOG.

Here is some example.

input: '(5 2 (3 5 (3) 5 (4 2 (2 4))) 5 2)

output: '(5 2 (3 () 5 (4 (2))))

Structure of the output list remains the same.

Thanks for advice,

Comment: You probably forgot the `homework` tag.

Comment: It is not iobvious from the data what element you're wanting to have removed, You start out with 2s, 3s, 4s and 5s, you finish with the same elements present. Yet, the problem description indicates that one shuold be completely gone.

Comment: I want every even appearance of each element from the list to be removed. That means second, fourth and so on... The structure of the list must remain the same.

'(5 2 (3 **5** (**3**) 5 (4 **2** (2 **4**))) **5** **2**)

The bold items must be removed.

Answer (score 2):

Since this appears to be a homework, I am going to provide only a pointer to the solution:

- Review the [REMOVE-IF](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rm_rm.htm) predicate in Common Lisp. (It may not do everything you need...)
- Build a recursive walker.
- Consider how you will pass the state back and forth.

As an aside, I highly recommend posting a snippet of your work to date and asking a specific question. A generalized question such as the above seems to suggest you want a solution dropped in your lap.

Okay, it's not homework. And I got intellectually intrigued. I solved it.

It's a recursive walker. If your Lisp does TCO, it should be transformable into a TCO.

You can do it in a loop, but that would require maintaining a stack list to handle the "go into list" case.

I make no claims to an idiomatic solution.

---

```
(defparameter input '(5 2 (3 5 (3) 5 (4 2 (2 4))) 5 2))

(defparameter output '(5 2 (3 () 5 (4 (2)))))

(defun remove-every-other-appearence (list &optional (hash-table nil))
  (when list                             ; termination condition
    ;(format t "~%~a~&" list)
    (unless hash-table                     ; if it's the first time
      ;(format t "creating hash table~&")
      (setf hash-table (make-hash-table))) ; create a hash table
    (let ((eut (car list)))                ; element under test
      ;(format t "eut: ~a~&" eut)
      (cond
        ((consp eut)                      ;Recursion time, it's a list.
         ;(format t "Recursing~&")
         (cons
          (remove-every-other-appearence eut hash-table)
          (remove-every-other-appearence (cdr list) hash-table)))
        (t                                ;Otherwise...
                                        ; Increment seen counter by 1
         (setf (gethash eut hash-table 0) 
               (1+ (gethash eut hash-table 0)))
         (cond
           ((evenp (gethash eut hash-table))
             (remove-every-other-appearence (cdr list) hash-table))
                                        ;ignore the element
           ((oddp (gethash eut hash-table))
                                        ; if this is the odd occurance
                                        ;cons the element back onto the rest of the list
            (cons eut (remove-every-other-appearence (cdr list) hash-table)))           
           (t
            (error "This integer is neither even nor odd. We're in trouble"))))))))
```

---

```
* input

(5 2 (3 5 (3) 5 (4 2 (2 4))) 5 2)
* (remove-every-other-appearence input)

(5 2 (3 NIL 5 (4 (2))))
* output

(5 2 (3 NIL 5 (4 (2))))
```

Comment: OK, this isn't homework and if it is I don't want my homework to be written by someone else. I just want help for idea how to do this because I don't have any idea. Give me pseudo code for example.

Thanks for advice,

Comment: @Unknown: you have to walk the list. I'm mucking about with it in my (copious, ha ha) spare time at work.

Comment: @Unknown: enjoy the solution. Prolog should be a simple transform from this one.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, your problem statement is rather unclear.

As I understand the question, the problem is that you have an arbitrary "tree", the non-leaf nodes of which are lists and the leaf nodes of which are something else. A "list of lists" as it were. You would like to view that as a *logical* flat sequence of leaf nodes, iterate over that and remove every other leaf node **without** altering the overall shape of the "tree", such that the only thing that changes is the number of leaves hanging from any given node.

From that, given the following inputs, you'd realize the corresponding outputs:

```
input:  []
output: []

input:  [a,b,c,d]
output: [a,c]

input:  [a,[],b,c,d]
output: [a,[],c]

input:  [a,[b],c,d]
output: [a,[],c]

input:  [a,[b,c,d,e],f,g]
output: [a,[c,e],g]

input:  [a,[b,[],[c,d,[e,f,g],h],i],j]
output: [a,[[],[c,[e,g]],i]]
```

Here's an [untested] prolog solution. In it, I just maintaining two states, `keep` and `remove` and toggle between them as needed. You get odd/even for free: it just depends on the state in which you start the machine.

It should be noted that if the data structure passed in contains any unbound/non-unified variables, you're unlike to get correct results. Unwanted unification causes problems. Guard clauses would need to be added to properly handle with them.

```
% ====================
% The public interface
% ====================
remove_even( Xs , Ys ) :- remove_every_other_node( keep   , _ , Xs , [] , Ys ).
remove_odd(  Xs , Ys ) :- remove_every_other_node( remove , _ , Xs , [] , Ys ).

%------------------
% The core iterator
%------------------
remove_every_other_node( S , S , [] , T , List ) :-
  reverse(T,List)
  .
remove_every_other_node( S , N , [X|Xs] , T , List ) :-
  process_node( S, S1 , X , T , T1 ) ,
  remove_every_other_node( S1 , N , Xs , T1 , List )
  .

%----------------------
% The list node handler
%----------------------
process_node( S , S , []     , T , [[]|T] ).
process_node( S , N , [X|Xs] , T , [L1|T] ) :-
  remove_every_other_node( S , N , [X|Xs] , [] , L1)
  .
process_node( keep   , remove , X , T , [X|T] ).
process_node( remove , keep   , X , T , T     ).
```

Comment: You are right maybe my question is not clear enough. I have to remove second, fourth etc DUPLICATES in the list. So i get first element and look for any second, fourth appearance in the list and if I have that I remove that elements, after that I get second element and repeat previous procedure.

Answer (score 0):

```
(defun rea (tree)
  (let ((table (make-hash-table)))
    (labels ((fn (x)
               (unless (and x (atom x) (evenp (incf (gethash x table 0))))
                 (list (if (atom x) x (mapcan #'fn x))))))
      (car (fn tree)))))
```